# php: if property doesn't exist

Tags: php, sql

I just encountered a problem which is new to me and I found 2 solutions... this question is basically about finding a better or cleaner one if there is !

In my DB, I store some preferences for every user about his daily schedule. The first time the user connects, the DB doesn't have any infos so I'm running this code:

```
if(!empty($opening_h->{'lunch'}) == true) 
{ 
    if($opening_h->{'lunch'} == 1) 
    {
        echo 'checked';
    };
};
```

PS: there are multiple values in there, encoded in json format.

Is there a better way? The other one I could think about would be to write

```
lunch => 0, dinner => 0
```

when the user registers to the platform... but that seems silly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd personally use `!empty`; checking against 0 may cause issues if it's null?

Comment: I don't encounter the null case since the db field is either empty or all cases are defined by true or false.
So there's no shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **__isset** magic method in your class for *$opening_h* to check whether the property exists first and to do something if not. Then, when you're sure your property exists, you can easily write something like:

```
if($opening_h->{'lunch'} == 1) {
    echo 'checked';
};
```

With the **__isset** now it looks simpler.

Comment: How does that treat null records?

Comment: If the value is null then the condition $opening_h->{'lunch'} == 1 won't throw any error and at the same time will fail. If there's a need to treat nulls specifically, then one can use is_null() in the condition